# Dynamic JSON-graph drawing with Sigma.js

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, sigma.js

I'm trying to draw a JSON file that is uploaded on a form, so it can be displayed in a page using Sigma, but I don't want to mix PHP and JS code in a same file so I don't know how to pass the variable containing the JSON file path to the drawing function in my .js.

I have the following files (I'm omitting the form code, it's an input-file like any other):

**upload.php:** (form action references this)

```
<?php 
$target_path = "uploads/";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); // this is what I need to pass to the script 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) 
    { 
        echo "The file has been uploaded. File path is ".$target_path; // manual validation
    } 
else
    {
        echo "Error, try again";
    }
?>
```

**drawer.js** (this is in a different folder "graph/drawer.js")

```
 sigma.parsers.json("data.json", // Here I need to put the filepath instead of "data.json"
    {
    container: document.getElementById('container'),
    settings: {
      defaultNodeColor: '#ec5148',
      edgeColor: 'default',
      defaultEdgeColor: 'grey'
    }
  });
```

I'm thinking of using AJAX to upload the content page with the displayed graph but I need to do this first, and I have to do it this way so JS and PHP code is not mixed (also for separating modules). I'm not using any kind of framework for the moment. Can anyone help me with the best way to do what I'm asking? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understoond your problem correctly,
you need to have a separate file for handling the php uploading file
and a second file that will be used as a provider for the graph json file for the graph.

on button click listener something like

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:upload_handler.php'
....
```

upload.php

the code you already have+transfer the data to your second php file or save to db
if you are going to have many users

js request for json data

sigma.parsers.json(/path_to/phpAPI.php,...

```
enter code here
```

phpAPI.php

1.retrieve data from db or directly from upload.php

2.send data to client

Comment: how would I do this for a web form using ASP.NET's upload file? Can I still use a php script (i.e. phpAPI.php)?